# how to run angular 6 app with nodejs api on production?

Tags: node.js, angular, angular6, node-request

Hi I am new to angular6

In development mode I have worked in angular 4200 port and node in different port (8080) in my operations.
but now I want to move my app into production mode. 
for that I had build my angular project by using **`ng build`** command. after i get a dist folder is created on the root folder.

so i went to server.js file 
here I  had add my static file

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'dist/MDProject')));

app.use('/',(req,res)=>{

    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'dist/MDProject/index.html'))
});
```

click here to read my [server.js](https://www.writeurl.com/text/kssiyj702qx55qwn5yne/w89tunlc54w2vf38qoq6) file

by this 
when ever I redirect to my local host it is opening but 
in server.js side i didn't get any response.

when ever I try to login I am getting this error.
[image]

can anyone help me to solve this

Comment: a request to `http://localhost:8085/login` is failing, could you add the details in the error?

Comment: in my angular app It is like this return this._http.get("http://localhost:8085/login",{
      observe:'body',
      withCredentials:true,
      headers:new HttpHeaders().append('Content-Type','application/json')
    });

Comment: again, there is an `error` property on the `HttpErrorResponse` instance. can you add its details? Specifically, the `text` property.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are 2 things wrong here in your code.

First, update your code

From:-

```
app.use('/',(req,res)=>{

    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'dist/MDProject/index.html'))
});
```

To:-  **This code needs to be added just before your `app.listen(app.get('port'))` code**

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
     res.sendfile('./public/MDProject/index.html'); 
     // load the single view file (angular will handle the page changes on the front-end)
});
```

Second, Serve your file from your `public` folder(In your case I think it is the `dist` folder). So update your code like this.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/MDProject'));
```

Comment: shall i share my sample code? Angular6 with node.js

Comment: Have to add required headers? While sending API req. in Angular. 
 `let headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });`

Comment: It is there in my service.ts file

Comment: You can also look into https://daveceddia.com/unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182937/discussion-between-vinoth-and-yashwardhan-pauranik).

Answer (score 1):

after I removed this line in my server.js file

```
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

and I paste this line before port creation.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'dist/MDProject')));

app.use('/',(req,res)=>{

    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'dist/MDProject/index.html'))
});
```

now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to go to index page.

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
 res.sendfile('./public/MDProject/index.html');
})
```

with that you have to make folder in public in node

```
app.use('/', express.static('/dist/MDProject'))
```

Then in your app dist folder -> index.html

```
<base href="http://192.168.1.1:3000/admin-panel/">
```

This is my working code. Let me know if you have still any issue. :)